# how to intent one activity into multiple activity without writing Activity.class for every Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

1. Such as i  have  AddActivity.java
2. Intent the AddActivity in Multiple Activity

such as SecondActivity & ThirdActivity  Intent the AddActivity
without writing SecondActivity.class & ThirdActivity.class.

I also want to  save data in secondActivity & thirdActivity in listView using AddActivity. AddActivity has firstname EditText and lastName EditText & save button.

Comment: what do you mean by "intent" used as verb?

Comment: confusing!!!!... i read it 4 times.. still didn't get.

Comment: Intent  intent = new Intent(this,Activity.class)

Comment: try using fragment instead of activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It is not possible to use one intent into multiple activities, 
   Intent intent = new Intent(CallerActivity, CalledActivity);